# How to prompt user to re-loop the whole program?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I want the user to choose between playing the game again or ending the program, however when prompted, if they press 'y' the same thing gets repeated over and over instead of the whole program from the very beginning. I've tried while loops, do/while loops, if statements, rearranging the code, but nothing has worked. Any advice?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string animal = "fish";
    string guess;
    char choose = 'Y' ;
    int count = 0;//keeps a running total of how many times the user 
has guessed an answer.
    int limit = 5;//allows user to guess only 5 times, otherwise 
they loose the game.
    bool out_of_guesses = false;//to check whether the user has run 
out of guesses.

    cout << "I am thinking of an animal.\n" << endl;

    do{
        while(animal != guess && !out_of_guesses){//Nested while 
loop inside main loop to keep track of how many tries the user has 
attempted and to validate their answers.
        if(count < limit){
            cout << "Can you guess what animal I am thinking of?: ";
            getline(cin, guess);
            count++;
            if(animal != guess){
                cout << "\nHmm, nope. That's not the animal I'm 
thinking of." << endl;
                if(count > 2 && count <5){
                    cout << "I'll give you a hint. It lives in 
water." << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            out_of_guesses = true;
        }
    }//End nested while loop
        if(out_of_guesses){
            cout << "\nI'm sorry, but you are out of guesses." << 
endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "\n*** Good job! You guessed the correct animal! 
***" << endl;
            cout << "\t\t><)))º> ❤ <º)))><\t\t" << endl;
        }

    //The do-while loop is there to ask the user if they wish to 
play the game again.
    cout << "Would you like to try again?(y/n): ";
    cin >> choose;
        if(choose == 'N' || choose == 'n')
            break;
    }while(choose == 'Y' || choose == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you run into a "how to prompt to re-run" question and you have nothing but one long sequence of code in `main()` -- it generally means you need refactor your code. For instance moving all of what constitutes playing the game into a separate function (such as `play_game()`. The "how to prompt to re-run?" becomes trivial, e.g. `int again = 0; do { play_game(); fputs ("play again? (y/n): ", stdout); again = getchar(); /* empty stdin here */ } while (tolower (again) == 'y');`

Answer (score 1):

The `bool out_of_guesses = false;` must be in-between `while(true)` and `while(animal != guess && !out_of_guesses)`, and not outside the first while loop. Because our while loop condition is always false, and then it does enter it.

You should also reset your `guess` variable in-between those 2 loops, else same thing could happen (false while loop) in case of the answer is found.

Here the code with some refactoring/review, which I used the guess as upper case to handle any typography of the answer. I also removed the out of guess variable to use the count and limit one instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    const std::string animal = "FISH";
    const int limit = 5;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "I am thinking of an animal.\n";

        int count = 0;
        std::string guess;    

        while(animal.compare(std::toupper(guess)) != 0 && count < limit)
        {
                std::cout << "Can you guess what animal I am thinking of?: \n";
                std::cin >> guess;
                count++;
                if(animal.compare(std::toupper(guess)) != 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "\nHmm, nope. That's not the animal I'm thinking of.\n";
                    if(count > 2)
                    {
                        std::cout << "I'll give you a hint. It lives in water.\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }//End nested while loop

        if(count >= limit)
        {
            std::cout << "\nI'm sorry, but you are out of guesses.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\n*** Good job! You guessed the correct animal! ***\n";
            std::cout << "\t\t><)))º> ❤ <º)))><\t\t\n";
        }

        char choose = 'Y' ;
        std::cout << "Would you like to try again?(y/n): ";
        std::cin >> choose;
        if(std::toupper(choose) == 'N') break;

    } while(true);

    return 0;
}
```